# MeteorJS: Users collection how to expose new field

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, meteorite

I have added new field in user collection but when I access it in the client side Meteor.user().cart ( cart is my new field). Its undefined. How can expose new field (cart) so that it can be access in the client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to add a `null` publisher which will automatically send the data without the need for a subscription. Be sure to limit the fields to only the ones you need.

```
Meteor.publish(null, function() {
  return Meteor.users.find(this.userId, {fields: {cart: 1}});
});
```

Comment: after I publish it can I just used it like  Meteor.user().cart?

Comment: Yes. Try it and let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: I got this error Exception from sub id undefined ReferenceError: Users is not defined

Comment: Sorry - typo. Try again.