# How do I extend User model in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, class, meteor

I have been researching this for ages and cannot find a clear explanation. My meteor app has user accounts installed and logging in/out is all working just fine. However, I'd like to add some optional fields to my users, such as age, gender, etc. How do I go about doing this? Please note, I am new to Meteor so please be explicit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MeteorJS: Users collection how to expose new field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383464/meteorjs-users-collection-how-to-expose-new-field).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add more fields to the user registration form provided by `useraccounts` packages, see [Form Fields Configuration](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md#form-fields-configuration) section of the official [Guide](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md)

Supposing you want to add a `gender` field to the registration form, you could do something like this

```
AccountsTemplates.addField({
  _id: "gender",
  type: "select",
  displayName: "Gender",
  select: [
    {
      text: "Male",
      value: "male",
    },
    {
      text: "Female",
      value: "female",
    },
  ],
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation you're looking for is the [Meteor.users](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users) collection. It's under "Full API" at http://docs.meteor.com, which might explain why you've missed it.

> A user document can contain any data you want to store about a user. Meteor treats the following fields specially:
>
> - username: a unique String identifying the user.
> - emails: [...]
> - createdAt: the Date at which the user document was created.
> - profile: an Object which the user can create and update with any data. Do not store anything on profile that you wouldn't want the user to edit unless you have a deny rule on the Meteor.users collection.
>
> [...]
>
> By default, the current user's username, emails and profile are published to the client. You can publish additional fields for the current user with:

```js
// server
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
                             {fields: {'other': 1, 'things': 1}});
  } else {
    this.ready();
  }
});

// client
Meteor.subscribe("userData");
```

Comment: I think using a `null` publisher is better in this case. See the linked question above.

Answer (score 1):

Check the simple schema package, this package has an example of that

https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/simple-schema