# Check if a field in Meteor.users collection is true / false?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have a field in the `Meteor.users` collection that can be set to `true` or `false`. I want to check if the field for the current user is equal to `true` or `false`.

How would this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**inside a template**

```html
{{#if currentUser.isAwesome}}
  <p>You are awesome!</p>
{{/if}}
```

**inside a publish function**

```js
Meteor.publish('something', function() {
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
  if (user.isAwesome)
    console.log('You are awesome!');
});
```

**anywhere else**

```js
if(Meteor.user().isAwesome)
  console.log('You are awesome!');
```

Note: If your custom field isn't visible on the client, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383464/meteorjs-users-collection-how-to-expose-new-field).

Comment: ty (extra text for dumb minimum characters)